# How to run periodic tasks concurrently with Celery and Django

Tags: python, django, celery

I have some tasks being running by celery in my Django project.

I use contrab to specify the time the task should be run, like this:

```
from celery.schedules import crontab

CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'task_a': {
        'task': 'tasks.task_a',
        'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour='5,18'),
    },
    'task_b': {
        'task': 'tasks.task_b',
        'schedule': crontab(minute=4, hour='5,18'),
    },
}
```

What has been happening is that one task is executed, and only about 5 minutes later the other starts. When they should be executed at the same time.

I would like all of them to be started at the same, but this it's not what is happening

*there are about eight tasks in total, some of which take a long time to complete*

I am using the following command at the moment

initially, it was like this

```
celery -A api worker  --concurrency=4 -n <name>
```

then I tried

```
celery -A api multi  --concurrency=4 -n <name>
```

and finally

```
celery -A api multi -P gevent --concurrency=4 -n <name>
```

They are all shared_tasks

```
@shared_task(bind=True, name="tasks.task_a")
def task_a(self):
     pass
```

and I'm using `autodiscover_tasks`

```
app = Celery('<app-name>')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it might be a hardware issue. Make sure you have enough CPU resource available to the celery worker.

Concurrency should be set to the number of CPUs available on your machine (which is default). If your tasks are CPU bound, the pool should be set to `prefork` (which is default) and not `gevent` (which is for I/O bound like HTTP requests)

Celery `multi` is to start multiple works. Generally Celery's default advise is 1 worker per machine. But they do tell you to do your own testing.

Edit: This link does a great job at explaining: https://www.distributedpython.com/2018/10/26/celery-execution-pool/

Comment: I have 8 CPU on this server. I'm running 3 workers with this same configuration (for 3 different apps). Shouldn't it be enough? how could I check this out?

Comment: Assuming if CPU usage and memory seem normal. Check the connection to your queue. Else you could try [prefetch](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/optimizing.html#prefetch-limits) 
 setting if your tasks are short

Comment: celery runs prefetch as default

Comment: I meant that you can increase / decrease prefetch depending on your tasks